# what is the difference between these 2 python codes, and why the out put is not same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

these are the 2 python3 code,

```
{w for w in words if w[::-1] in words and len(w)==4}
```

```
{w for w in words if w==w[::-1]and len(w)==4}
```

In my point, w is the word in words, so **w** should equal with  **words**，but the output is differently. Could someone help me, why the output is different?

Comment: One version is testing if the reversed w is in the list; the other is testing if w is a palindrome. Very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `words` is `{'abba', 'abcd', 'dcba'}` then the result of the first code will be `{'abba', 'abcd', 'dcba'}` while the second will return `{'abba'}`.

`w==w[::-1]` checks if the word is equal to its reverse while `w[::-1] in words` checks if the reverse of `w` is in `words`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess those code sanples are doing really different things.

```
{w for w in words if w[::-1] in `words` and len(w)==4}
```

It includes element `w` from itterable `words` if only reversed `w` ("ABCD" => "DCBA") is also present at `words` and it's length is 4.

```
{w for w in words if w==w[::-1]and len(w)==4}
```

This includes element `w` from `words` if only `w` is equal to reversed `w` itself ("abba" = "abba") and it's length is 4